# What guarantees the existence of smallest infinite sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have seen definitions like this in several places

> Define $\Phi$ to be the **smallest** set that such that
>
> 1. Whenever $p \in \mathcal{P}$, we have $p \in \Phi$
> 2. Whenever $\alpha \in \Phi$, we have $\neg \alpha \in \Phi$
> 3. Whenever $\alpha, \beta \in \Phi$, we have $(\alpha \implies \beta) \in \Phi$

What guarantees the existence of a smallest set? Why can't there be a family of sets satisfying all the conditions such that given any set of the family, there exists a set smaller than it?

Comment: You are comparing sets with respect to inclusion. To say that $\Phi$ is smallest means, first, that there are sets with the desired property, second, in fact, $\Phi$ has the desired property and, third, $\Phi$ is contained (as a subset) in any set having the property.

Answer (score 5):

In general, just saying "the smallest set that satisfies such and such condition" can be dangerous, but in your particular case, $\Phi$ is well defined, because if $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is any family of sets that satisfies the three conditions, then

$$A=\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$$

also satisfies all three conditions, and $A$ is smaller than all the sets in the family.

---

To prove the claim I made:

Say $A_i$ satisfies all three conditions for all $i\in I$. Then, let's say that $p\in \mathcal P$.

Let $i\in I$. Then, because $p\in \mathcal P$, we have $p\in A_i$ (because $A_i$ satisfies condition 1). But because $i$ was arbitrary, we know that $$\forall i\in I: p\in A_i$$

which is the same as $p\in A$. So, $A$ satisfies condition 1.

---

Now let's say $\alpha\in A$. Let $i\in I$.

From $\alpha\in \bigcap A_i$, we know that $\alpha \in A_i$. Since $A_i$ satisfies condition 2, we know $\neg \alpha \in A_i$. Therefore, since $i$ was arbitrary, we have $$\forall i \in I: \neg \alpha \in A$$ or, in other words, $\neg\alpha\in A$. So, $A$ satisfies condition 2.

---

Say $\alpha, \beta\in\Phi$. Then again, $\alpha, \beta\in A_i$, therefore $\alpha\implies\beta\in A_i$, and therefore $\alpha\implies\beta\in A$, so $A$ satisfies condition 3.

Comment: Okay, but I really wanted to ask this as a meta-question, not specific to these formulae. For example, what if somebody says naturals numbers are the smallest set that satisfy these <axioms>

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay Then, as I said, it may no be a well defined set. There are some conditions for which "the smallest set that satisfies these conditions" exists (like your example), and others where such a set either does not exist (for example, the smallest real interval with two at least two points) or may not be unique (like the smalest nonempty subset of $\mathbb N$).